did my ubuntu upgrade?
I just upgraded from 22.04 lts to 24.04 lts but it seems to not have changed.
As you can see in the first picture i have 24.04 installed, but the menu did not change, nor did my files explorer.
is there something i missed in the installation?



A system that is release-upgraded will keep the users old defaults; ie. the underlying OS is upgraded, but any changes/settings you made are kept so it'll still work as it did before... causing a release-upgraded system to look different to a clean or fresh installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS system.  I'm not sure what you're worried about, but I wonder if you're expecting it to look like a clean install; and missing that it preserved your settings as that is what most users prefer (thus who want fresh, usually re-install).
